# How to Adjust the Timer Text and "Time is Up" Text in 10 minute countdown timer using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I have this line of codes where you can set a timer in html using javascript that displays a time out text after the countdown. You can refer to this link https://codepen.io/rxsharp/pen/jPZgpX

This is the Javascript code

```
<script>
function countdown( elementName, minutes, seconds )
{
var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

function twoDigits( n )
{
    return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
}

function updateTimer()
{
    msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
    if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {
        element.innerHTML = "Time is up!";
    } else {
        time = new Date( msLeft );
        hours = time.getUTCHours();
        mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
        element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits( 
time.getUTCSeconds() );
        setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );
    }
}

element = document.getElementById( elementName );
endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
updateTimer();
}

countdown( "ten-countdown", 10, 0 );
</script>
```

The HTML displayed code

```
<div id="ten-countdown"></div>
```

I want to know How to adjust, edit, modify the "10:00" Text that changes, even the "Time is Up!" text after the countdown ends. Any Help will be greatly appreciated!, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the time of the countdown by modifying the `countdown( "ten-countdown", 10, 0 );` line at the end of the Javascript code.

The second parameter (10) is the minutes, and the third (0) one is the seconds as it can be understoodd through the signature of the method, at the start: `function countdown( elementName, minutes, seconds )`.

To change the "Time is up" text, you can change the 16th line: `element.innerHTML = "Time is up!";`.

Do not hesitate to search with ctrl+f in the code if you want to find a specific text.

Comment: It really help me a lot, I can even change the layout-design thanks.

Comment: If so, please vote the answer as the correct one to indicate to future readers that it helped. Thanks for the feedback!